# Undefined name 'context' (in Flutter Navigation)

Tags: flutter, dart

So I was trying to navigate from one screen to another, using Navigator.push (not using NamedRoutes). But suddenly I am getting this error of Undefined name 'context'. I want to navigate from the 'loading_screen.dart' to 'context_screen.dart'. I am not understanding why I am facing this error.

loading_screen.dart

```
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  String searchTerm;
  LoadingScreen({this.searchTerm});

  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}


class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("On Loading Screen");
    String searchTerm = widget.searchTerm;
    getMeaning(searchTerm);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitWave(
          color: kMainBlueColor,
          size: 70.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void getMeaning(String searchTerm) async {
  print(searchTerm);
  // TODO: get the meaning of the search term.
  // TODO: Test without net and see background loading
  var searchContext;
  // var searchContext = await .....
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return ContextScreen(searchContext: searchContext);
  }));
}
```

context_screen.dart

```
class ContextScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final searchContext;
  ContextScreen({this.searchContext});

  @override
  _ContextScreenState createState() => _ContextScreenState();
}

class _ContextScreenState extends State<ContextScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var searchContext = widget.searchContext;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  int count = 0;
                  Navigator.of(context).popUntil((context) => count++ >= 2);
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  color: kMainBlueColor,
                  size: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                searchContext
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I have neglected the import statements above, but I have added them in my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the whole error statement?

Comment: Compiler message:
lib/screens/loading_screen.dart:47:18: Error: Getter not found: 'context'.
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                 ^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can move `getMeaning` into `_LoadingScreenState` and use `addPostFrameCallback`

code snippet

```
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  void getMeaning(String searchTerm) async {
    print(searchTerm);
    // TODO: get the meaning of the search term.
    // TODO: Test without net and see background loading
    var searchContext = "";
    // var searchContext = await .....
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    });

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return ContextScreen(searchContext: searchContext);
    }));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("On Loading Screen");
    String searchTerm = widget.searchTerm;

    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getMeaning(searchTerm);
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String searchTerm;
  LoadingScreen({this.searchTerm});

  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  void getMeaning(String searchTerm) async {
    print(searchTerm);
    // TODO: get the meaning of the search term.
    // TODO: Test without net and see background loading
    var searchContext = "";
    // var searchContext = await .....
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    });

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return ContextScreen(searchContext: searchContext);
    }));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("On Loading Screen");
    String searchTerm = widget.searchTerm;

    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getMeaning(searchTerm);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitWave(
          color: Colors.blue,
          size: 70.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContextScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final searchContext;
  ContextScreen({this.searchContext});

  @override
  _ContextScreenState createState() => _ContextScreenState();
}

class _ContextScreenState extends State<ContextScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var searchContext = widget.searchContext;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                int count = 0;
                Navigator.of(context).popUntil((context) => count++ >= 2);
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(searchContext),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: LoadingScreen(searchTerm: "test"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have called a method in `initState` which is using context.`context` is only available after completion of `initState`.

So you can call the method in `didChangeDependencies`, which is called immediately after `initState`.

To know more about `didChangeDependencies`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html

To know more about StatefulWidget lifecycle : https://medium.com/flutter-community/widget-state-buildcontext-inheritedwidget-898d671b7956

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have tried this before, and it had worked perfectly. In place of a TODO, I have to make an API call. Therefore I made it async, but it still giving the same issue.

Comment: put the method call in didChangeDependencies or add some delay time.

Comment: Thanks alot for the follow up. But I'm getting a compile time error and not a run time error. Therefore adding some delay time or calling didChangeDependencies may not work here.

As the error is showing before the app even compiles.

UPDATE: I tried it, and  still the error persists.